# Upgrade from ExtJS 3.4.1 to 7.5.0

Tags: extjs, upgrade

Apparently, the ExtJS' forum isn't working anymore, so asking the question here.

I am trying to upgrade ExtJS integrated in a big application. Currently, it's using version 3.4.1 and I have to upgrade it to 7.5.0, so a lot of changes are expected. It's my first time working with ExtJS. I've been reading their documentation & examples for a while now, but I'm having issues understanding some things.

If someone's experienced with ExtJS, could you tell how big is the difference between these versions? What kind of effort is expected for this upgrade? Will I have to rewrite everything, or just changing files and API calls would be enough?

Another thing is that the folder structure in the new version looks quite different from the older version. Ours using 3.4.1 looks like this -

[ext-js 3.4.1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/246TJ.png)

There are no new `adapter` or `resources` folders in the new verion. Are these folders not required anymore, or is it possible to get the same folder structure with the new version?

Is it possible to download older versions of ExtJS like 4.x, 5.x etc.? I tried but couldn't find it, I was able to download the older documentation though.

Downloaded the latest ExtJS version from [here](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/).

Referring this [Sencha ExtJS documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_with_zip.html).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The biggest jump was probably 4 to 5, that's where MVVM was introduced.  Versions 5 to 7 did not have drastic changes.

Have you looked at upgrade guides from Sencha?  Each version listed changes, so you'll probably either have to go version by version, or maybe 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 7.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 2):

**Download**

You should download the version from `support.sencha.com`. There you can find all versions.

To access the download page, you need to log in. If you have lost your login, you can contact Sencha's licensing department.

Make sure you have a valid license.

**Upgrade**

If you are new to Sencha, you should not do the work yourself. Between version 3 and 7, there are at least two new coding paradigms and you'll have to rewrite everything. Unfortunately, there is no easy upgrade process from 3 to 7. If you had to upgrade from 5 to 7, it would be possible to ignore all the cool new features, but if you are starting from 3, you will have to rewrite everything.

**Building process**

In your screenshot, I can see that you are using the full ExtJS file. But are you really building the application? That means you end up with a single js file and a single css file.

- Are you building your application?
- Are you using SCSS?

You should definitely contact someone with experience. I've done quite a few upgrades in ExtJS to know that you need help with this.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not building the application from scratch and we do have source control (TFVC). Basically our ExtJS makes the UI of our whole app, and lots of code of custom components are written using ExtJS, and the task now would be to re-write them to upgrade ExtJS (as you mentioned). I didn't know that after logging into Sencha's support account, we could access older versions, I'll ask someone else in my team for the credentials.
I was using trial version for research purposes till now.

Comment: If one had to estimate How much time do you think that it would take to learn the extJs and start upgrading ?

Comment: How long it takes to learn ExtJS to upgrade: 6 months I would say. It would be way easier to start the upgrade with a pro and then take over after 3 months.

Comment: But that said. ExtJS overall is easy to learn. But since you have to know a lot more to upgrade a full application, I suggested half a year. To learn ExtJS basics takes only a week. But again, better to get a teacher AND do a code review after a month. I always suggest to my customers to take the code review first, but in your case it should come second.